# How to separate home page for user and admin after they login/signin?

Tags: php, html

I have problem where when I'm login as a user or admin it will go to the same page which is home.php. So the solution that i want is I want to have user and admin home.php of their own. Here is my code for login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("functions.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <title>Signin Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


  </head>

  <body class="text-center">
      <?php
      
        if(isset($_POST['signin'])){
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $query = "SELECT * from `accounts`;";
            if(count(fetchAll($query)) > 0){ //this is to catch unknown error.
                  foreach(fetchAll($query) as $row){
                    if($row['email']==$email&&$row['password']==$password){
                        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['type'] = $row['type'];
                        header('location:home.php'); //Here is the problem
                    }else{
                        echo "<script>alert('Wrong login details.')</script>";
                    }
                }
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('Error.')</script>";
            }

        }
      
      ?>
      <div class="container">
            <form method="post" class="form-signin">
              <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
              <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
                
                
              <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
              <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
              <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
              <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
             
              <button name="signin" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
              <a href="signup.php" class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">Create an account</a>
            </form>
          </div>
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

..........................................................................................................

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Comment: Also note, you're selecting every row from the database and then looping over them in your code looking for the right user. Instead, add a `WHERE` clause to your SQL so that you select only the one row for the user attempting to log in.

Comment: In order to redirect to a different page, you'll need some mechanism to tell the difference between a regular user and an admin user. Do you have that? Some sort of flag, or field that indicates the user is an admin?

Comment: This only assignment purpose only, so plain text passwords is to ease lecturer see the details in database

Comment: Could you suggest what row should be select ?

Comment: In my table, only have type field, in type field it record whether user or admin

Comment: Ok, so then just write an `if()` statement that looks at that field, and then redirects to either page based on its contents. Note you usually want to `exit()` after issuing a redirect header, else the rest of the page will still be processed.

Comment: I think you will have to get role of login users and change your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for type and then redirect accordingly:

```
$_SESSION['type'] = $row['type'];
if ($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin') {
  header('location:admin-home.php'); 
}
else {
  header('location:home.php'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your folder/file is structured but here is a pointer

Check `if ($row['type'] == 'admin')` then redirect to the admin path however you like `header('location:admin.php');` then `else if ($row['type'] == 'user')` then redirect to the user path `header('location:user.php');`

You can then use an "else" to redirect to and error page if user type is neither

Answer (score 0):

use better query

```
$query = "SELECT * from `accounts` WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1;";
```

and use this to redirect to their own homepage.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){
    $type = $_SESSION['type'];
    if($type = "admin"){
        header('location: home-admin.php');
    }else{
        header('location: home-user.php');
    }
    exit();
}
```